# Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled banner

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to mimic this site's Javascipt required banner, and have the below divs which are being hidden if javascript is allowed/enabled, but I am getting a flash/glimps of it on page load.

```
<div id="Main_noJS">Craftystuff.com works best with JavaScript enabled</div>
<div id="PartOfMain_noJS"><br /></div>
```

CSS:

```
#Main_noJS {
    width: 100%;
    height: 23px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 111%;
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #AE0000;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// hide the "Craftystuff.com works best with JavaScript enabled" banner, if JavaScript is working
if ($("#Main_noJS")) {
    $("#Main_noJS").hide();
    // hide the spacer between the main content and banner...
    $("#PartOfMain_noJS").hide();
}
```

So the banner is visible to start with, and only when javascript is enabled do I hide it

- but javascript must take a second to get to work to hide things...

I would like to try to stop the glimps of the banner, when the page first loads, any help?

Comment: Rightclick here, choose *View Source*, scroll to bottom, check the code containing the text "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled". Do you see it?

Answer (score 7):

Put the banner in a a `<noscript>` tag, documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp).

```
<noscript>
   <div>yada yada yada</div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write out a tag that hides the element while the page loads, then it won't be visible waiting for the script to run:

```
<script>document.write('<div style="display:none;">');</script>
<div id="Main_noJS">Craftystuff.com works best with JavaScript enabled</div>
<script>document.write('</div>');</script>
```