# JS is turned off in browser - alert doesn't show up?

Tags: javascript

I want to send a message to a user who turned off Javascript off on their Chrome. However its not working.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pSLkLfj.png]

whats wrong with this code

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: You're using javascript to detect when javascript is disabled.  Try `<noscript>JS not supported</noscript>`

Comment: If Javascript is turned off you can't run Javascript. Enclose an error message in `<nscript></noscript>`

Comment: @lante: It makes as much sense as asking why I can't see anything if I close my eyes.

Comment: it doesnt matter the sense, its a question at the end, and it has an answer. It makes much more sense than people suggesting jQuery as @FelipeP does.

Comment: @lante: Yeah... I'm sure he's joking. But your answer below doesn't answer the actual question. It provides an alternative, but doesn't address what is actually asked. *Q: What's wrong with this code? A: You can't.* Huh?

Comment: @lante, just in case you don't know about this http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: @FelipeP - most hilarious thing I've seen on Stack.

Comment: I am a terrible troll. Me and my mates were laughing our ass off when planning this but the reception is not what we expected.

Comment: how do you call it when someone trolls the troll? :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a serious question. Also it's basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3028806/218196.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `<noscript>Your browser doesn't support javascript.</noscript>`

Answer (score 1):

You cant, use the [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show an alert, if there is no JavaScript.
Instead use a noscript tag like:

```
<noscript><p class="alert">No JavaScript</p></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the noscript tag:

```
<noscript>


    This site requires JavaScript. You see this because you have it disabled.

  ...
</noscript>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use <noscript> tag to check and redirect the user so that he can know javascript is disabled   

 <noscript>
        <style type="text/css">
            .pagecontainer {display:none;}
        </style>
        <div class="noscriptmessage">
        You don't have javascript enabled.  
        </div>
    </noscript>
```